# R How to count occurrence of factor levels

Tags: r, aggregate, sequence

I have data in the following format:

```
ID    Task1   Task2   Task3   Task4
abc   Hard    Hard    Mix     Hard              
xyz   Easy    Mix     Easy    Hard               
als   Mix     Hard    Easy    Hard               
bld   Hard    Mix     Easy    Easy               
cqr   Hard    Easy    Hard    Hard               
alx   Hard    Hard    Hard    Hard
```

For each *ID*, I am interested in counting the occurrence of each factor level separately - Hard, Mix and Easy in this case (see below). I want to have a count of total occurrence per ID per factor and then I also want to have the count of maximum consecutive occurrence for that ID for that factor e.g.,

```
ID    Task1   Task2   Task3   Task4   Hard_Total   Max_Consecutive_Hard
abc   Hard    Hard    Mix     Hard    3            2
xyz   Easy    Mix     Easy    Hard    1            1
als   Mix     Hard    Easy    Hard    2            1
bld   Hard    Mix     Easy    Easy    1            1
cqr   Hard    Easy    Hard    Hard    3            2
alx   Hard    Hard    Hard    Hard    4            4
```

Could anyone please suggest a solution to this?

The dput() for the sample data is below.

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("abc","als", "alx", "bld", "cqr", "xyz"), class = "factor"), Task1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Easy", "Hard", "Mix"), class = "factor"), Task2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Easy", "Hard", "Mix"), class = "factor"), Task3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Easy", "Hard", "Mix"), class = "factor"), Task4 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Easy", "Hard"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: transform lo long format and use grouping operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rowSums()` to get the total number of `Hard` values by row and then use `rle()` rowwise to get the longest run:

```
transform(df, Hard_Total = rowSums(df[paste0("Task", 1:4)] == "Hard", na.rm = TRUE),
              Max_Consecutive_Hard = apply(df[paste0("Task", 1:4)], 1, function(x) with(rle(x), max(lengths[values == "Hard"], na.rm = TRUE))))

   ID Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4 Hard_Total Max_Consecutive_Hard
1 abc  Hard  Hard   Mix  Hard          3                    2
2 xyz  Easy   Mix  Easy  Hard          1                    1
3 als   Mix  Hard  Easy  Hard          2                    1
4 bld  Hard   Mix  Easy  Easy          1                    1
5 cqr  Hard  Easy  Hard  Hard          3                    2
6 alx  Hard  Hard  Hard  Hard          4                    4
```

Comment: Many thanks, what if the data has NAs? Where should I add condition to check for NAs as I think the code would not work.

Comment: If you have `NA` values and you want to ignore them, add the `na.rm = TRUE` argument to both the `rowSums()` and `max()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

First we make functions to get both columns you need `fun_hard` and `fun_max`. `fun_hard()` calculates number of "Hard" appearances in input while `fun_max()` calculates maximum consecutive "Hard' appearances in input using `rle()`.

```
fun_hard = function(x) {
  sum(x=="Hard")
}

fun_max = function(x) {
  rle_hard <- rle(x)
  max(rle_hard$lengths[rle_hard$values == "Hard"])
}
```

We use `apply()` to employ `fun_hard()` and `fun_max()` on each row of given `df`.

```
test_df$Hard_Total = apply(test_df[,c(2,3,4,5)], MARGIN = 1, FUN = fun_hard)
test_df$Max_Consecutive_Hard = 
              apply(test_df[,c(2,3,4,5)], MARGIN = 1, FUN = fun_max)
```

Output:

```
  ID Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4 Hard_Total Max_Consecutive_Hard
1 abc  Hard  Hard   Mix  Hard          3                    2
2 xyz  Easy   Mix  Easy  Hard          1                    1
3 als   Mix  Hard  Easy  Hard          2                    1
4 bld  Hard   Mix  Easy  Easy          1                    1
5 cqr  Hard  Easy  Hard  Hard          3                    2
6 alx  Hard  Hard  Hard  Hard          4                    4
```